# DB - Where to start from?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I want to start working with databases using the .NET framework.

1. From where can I download free Microsoft SQL?
2. Is there any tutorial for how to build and config a db and how to declare on tables and such

I got all the thoracic knowledge and i know the SQL Lang but i have never build db from scratch or used SQL queries using c# so this is my main problem i have been looking for guidance for at least a week but nothing truly explain the basics i know SQL!!! my problems are:

1. in which software, program to produce the DB?
2. how to connect to the DB using visual studio 2010?

to all of you thank you so much for helping me it means a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to start by downloading [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/), then read an [Overview of ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(VS.71).aspx)

You'll want to use [SQL Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en) to manage your database, create tables, etc. The most straightforward way to run a query (without any ORM, etc) from .NET would be to use a SqlConnection and [SqlCommand](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson03.aspx) to execute a query. That should get you started.

Comment: can you be more specific on how to do stuff step by step (the important ones I know how to program but in all the system/admin stuff I am pretty ignorant )
and cheers for the fast answer

Comment: @yoav Added a few more steps to my answer.

Comment: cheers mate ,@Bob your suggestion seems to be the best I have seen someone draws in 4 lines :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with SQL Server Express and build the tables using SQL Server Management Studio, but...

...before you start using the software to build your DB, know what your database is supposed to store and how you will retrieve the data from it.  Work out the details on paper, you know, drawing little squares with words inside them and with lines connecting them.  I know many "professionals" that their first step is to fire up the software and never look back.  This results in bad designs, poor table/column names, etc.  Get the tables, keys, columns and fk just about set before writing any code, otherwise you spend lots of time changing code to reflect "fixes" to your tables, or even worse, you'll just end up using the bad DB design and not changing it.  I add indexes later, as I work through the queries that pull the data out.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com) useful.

Comment: as i said i want to work with .net ' i already familiar with SQLite ... which is more useful in small storage such as android applications